# Android Studio build error or misconfigured

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having trouble building with Android Studio on one of my computers. The same project was building fine and when I pushed to github and pulled from the other machine I get the following error

```
   Argument 0 for @NotNull parameter of com/intellij/execution/configurations/GeneralCommandLine.setExePath must not be null
```

I tried generating a new default project and I get the same build error so it must be something with my setup.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix these issues? Or even how to completely uninstall Android Studio and start fresh? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had same error. In my case it was caused because of modification some important configuration. I fixed the issue by executing following steps:

1. File -> Other Settings -> Default Project Structure
2. SDKs
3. Add new SDK (select JDK option)
4. Specify path to JDK (in my case it was "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45")
5. Save changes

You can also check if you have configured path tho the Android SDK

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Had to uninstall Android Studio, delete all files related to it including install files, the .AndroidStudioPreview folder under your user directory, and those files made in your project's folder upon importing. This amounts to the idea folder and the [projectname].iml file. Now reinstall and re-import the project. You can reuse the same build.gradle. Mine's working now.

Comment: Thanks, I was not able to find a configuration file on my macbook, but I created a new user account and that did the trick so there must have been one but I could not find it. I searched (ls -a) a lot of folders for anything named .*android* with no luck.